# Arduino Yun and GoPro

Tags: python, node.js, arduino, npm, arduino-yun

I'm trying to control my GoPro with Arduino Yun and having some difficulty. Given this difficulty, I'm wondering if I'm going about it the right way and/or whether I should be trying something else instead.

Here's where I'm at:

1.) I've [installed node](http://blog.arduino.cc/2014/05/06/time-to-expand-your-yun-disk-space-and-install-node-js) on my Arduino

2.) I want to install either [gopro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gopro) or [gopro_hero_api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gopro_hero_api]gopro_hero_api) on my Yun, but I regularly get the error "FATAL ERROR: Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory -- Aborted"

3.) Ohhhh kaayyyy, so I find that I might need to [extend the RAM](http://www.element14.com/community/groups/arduino/blog/2014/12/19/part-x3-arduino-yun-extending-the-ram) on my Arduino with a [swap file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/). Except the command "dd" is not recognized by my Yun via ssh

4.) Now I'm stuck.

4a.)  Am I misunderstanding something about installing gopro_hero_api on my Yun? Is the gopro_hero_api not meant to be installed on my Yun and instead be installed and run from my machine?

4b.) The example usage shows the following. Where is this file saved and run from?:

```
  var Camera = require('gopro').Camera
  var cam = new Camera('10.5.5.9', 'camera password')

  cam.startCapture()
  .then(function() {
    cam.stopCapture()
  })
```

4c.)  As an alternative, I also found this: [GoPro Hero Python Library](http://goprohero.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Should I switch gears?
5.) Essentially my goal is to take a photo with three GoPros, send them somewhere where they can be sequenced and converted into a gif, and then displayed on a webpage. I'm open to doing anything that works. I've been trying new things and hitting all kinds of dead ends for the last few days. Can anyone weigh in on the recommended course of action from here?

**I'm looking to understand:**

- How to run node on my Yun.
- Whether or not I need to install gopro_hero_api on my Yun
- Where to save and run the code as per the example
- Whether or not I should continue with this method, or try the Python version, based on community advice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*dd* should be available on the Yun as it is a standard command included in BusyBox (small system binary for embedded Linux systems that contains all of the standard commands). What is the output that you are seeing when you try and run dd?

And yes, the "FATAL ERROR.." is related to Swap. Node.js will require quite a bit of RAM. You may indeed be better off using Python, simply from a resources standpoint.